# Determine whether $f'(1)= \lim \limits_{x \to 1}f'(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Determine whether $f'(1)= \lim \limits_{x \to 1}f'(x)$?

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
(x-1)^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right),  & \text{if $x$ $\ne$ 1} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x$  $=$ 1}
\end{cases}$$

I know the answer is false and they do not equal to each other. However why?

Comment: Did you try to calculate the derivative?

Comment: Note that $f'(1)=\lim_{x \to 1}f'(x)$ if and only if $f'(x)$ is a continuous function at $x=1$. Try to show that this is not the case.

Comment: The limit on the right does not exist

Answer (score 1):

To work out $f'(1)$ you calculate the derivative of when $x=1$. The derivative of 0 is 0. Therefore $f'(1) = 0$

Now what is $f'(x)?$

Using a combination of the product rule and chain rule we get $f'(x)= (2x-2)\cos(\frac{1}{x-1})+ \sin(\frac{1}{x-1})$.

Now the $\lim \limits_{x \to 1}f'(x)$ is undefined because $\lim \limits_{x \to 1}\sin(\frac{1}{x-1})$ does not exist.

Therefore we have $f'(1) \ne \lim \limits_{x \to 1}f'(x)$